# Why the move assignment of std::initializer_list was not blocked?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

It is clear that std::initializer_list is not an actual container.
The standard defines clearly what you can and cannot do with std::initializer_list.

But why does the language keep the option of doing foolish things, like **assigning a temporary std::initializer_list into another** - when it could have been easily **blocked** with =delete on std::initializer_list's move assignment operator?

Here is a broken code example, that compiles:

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<int> v) {
    std::cout << *v.begin() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    auto val = {a, b, c}; // ok, extending the lifetime of {a, b, c}
    foo(val); // prints ok
    int i = 7;
    val = {i}; // doesn't handle well assignment of temporary
    foo(val); // prints garbage...
}
```

**[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/661c40bf79bf895d), courtesy of @nwp:**

```
1
-365092848
```

Comment: Maybe It's the lack of sleep, but I absolutely can't see what would be wrong with your code. And of course, when testing it I fall in the "it looks like it works" case. What's going on exactly?

Comment: @Quentin [Can reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/661c40bf79bf895d).

Comment: [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) doesn't say anything about an assignment operator. Maybe the standard just doesn't say.

Comment: @Quentin this is _exactly_ why I believe the standard should have define a blocked move assignment (and probably `default` copy assignment and `default` copy ctor) -- because the defect in the code is hiding quite well, especially if you lack some sleep

Comment: Perhaps the answer is simply 'because no one filed a DR yet'... in which case, now's the time. Either that or they assume people read all the other stuff about the lifetime of the underlying array and won't do silly things, for which adding an explicit disallowance may not be worth the word count.

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2432. LWG kicked the ball to EWG's court back in 2015.